# Simple GCD utility in Java

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I [previously discussed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/81804/gcd-calculation-a-cross-of-the-euclidean-and-the-binary-algorithm) the performance concerns about different GCD algorithms. I wrote a simple Java class that implements the Binary GCD algorithm. It is a *really tiny* class that has only two easy-to-use methods. See for yourself:

### GCD.java

```
package math;

/**
 * This is a utility class that provides the functionality of calculating the
 * GCD or Greatest Common Divisor (also known as HCF or Highest Common
 * Factor) of two or more integers.
 * <p>
 * It has only two methods:
 * <ol>
 * <li>{@link #of(long, long)}</li>
 * <li>{@link #of(long, long, long...)}</li>
 * </ol>
 * Usage is very simple:
 * <pre><code>
 * ...
 * // assuming a, b, c, d and e are integers (long, int, etc.)
 * long gcd1 = GCD.of(a, b);
 * long gcd2 = GCD.of(a, b, c);
 * long gcd3 = GCD.of(a, b, c, d);
 * long gcd4 = GCD.of(a, b, c, e);
 * ...
 * </code></pre>
 *
 * @author Subhomoy Haldar
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class GCD {

    /**
     * Private constructor to prevent instantiation.
     */
    private GCD() {
        throw new Error("Instantiation not allowed.");
    }

    /**
     * This method computes the GCD of two positive integers using the Binary
     * GCD algorithm.
     * <p>
     * This method does not complain if the integers provided are negative.
     * In such a case, it simply the absolute value and performs the
     * computation. If one of the arguments is zero, the other argument is
     * returned. If both are zero, then zero is returned.
     *
     * @param a The first positive integer.
     * @param b The second positive integer.
     * @return The GCD of two positive integers.
     */
    public static long of(long a, long b) {
        // corner cases
        if (a == 0) return b;
        if (b == 0) return a;
        if (a < 0) a = -a;
        if (b < 0) b = -b;
        // number of tailing zeroes = power of 2 present
        int a0 = Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(a);
        int b0 = Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(b);
        // extract the the number of trailing zeroes common to them
        int commonPower = a0 < b0 ? a0 : b0;
        // make them odd
        a >>>= a0;
        b >>>= b0;
        while (a != b) {
            if (a > b) {
                a -= b;
                a >>>= Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(a);
            } else {
                b -= a;
                b >>>= Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(b);
            }
        }
        return a << commonPower; // multiply back the common power of 2
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the GCD of all the integers provided.
     * <p>
     * This method makes use of the {@link #of(long, long) of(long, long)}
     * method.
     *
     * @param a      The first positive integer.
     * @param b      The second positive integer.
     * @param others The other positive integers.
     * @return The GCD of all the integers provided.
     * @see #of(long, long) Internally used by this method.
     */
    public static long of(long a, long b, long... others) {
        long gcd = of(a, b);
        for (long number : others) {
            gcd = of(gcd, number);
        }
        return gcd;
    }
}
```

I welcome comments on any aspect of the code. This class will be reused in future questions.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of throwing an `Error`, an `AssertionError` would be better.
An `Error` is too broad.
An `AssertionError` conveys better that instantiating is an error by the programmer, violating a precondition.
(The only way this error will be triggered is if you try to create an instance within this class.)

```
private GCD() {
    throw new AssertionError("Instantiation not allowed.");
}
```

As this class has only private constructors,
it cannot be extended:
derived classes would need to call a constructor in the super-class,
but none are available.
To make the intention perfectly clear that this class is not designed to be extended, it's good to make it `final`.

Answer (score 5):

1. Mark the class `final` to make it obvious there are no and never will be any derived classes.
2. While your comments insist that the domain of `gcd` is non-negative integers, that doesn't conform to your code (which takes the absolute values), which gets it mostly right:

   - Only the absolute value is relevant for the gcd. Unfortunately, [you cannot negate the most-negative input-value (`Long.MIN_VALUE`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444611/math-abs-returns-wrong-value-for-integer-min-value), so you are forced to diagnose a domain-error there (throw an [`ArithmeticException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)).
   - If one argument is 0, the result is `abs(theother)`, not `theother`.
3. You could simplify the second function by only asking for a *single* fixed argument (or even no fixed arguments, with a result of 0).

   [What is \$gcd(0,a)\$, where a is a positive integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27719/what-is-gcd0-a-where-a-is-a-positive-integer)
   [What is \$gcd(0,0)\$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495119/what-is-gcd0-0)

   That probably doesn't improve performance though:

   ```
   public static long of(long a, long... others) {
       for (long number : others)
           a = of(a, number);
       return a;
   }
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   // The added iteration probably adds a really small penalty
   public static long of(long... others) {
       long a = 0;
       for(long number : others)
           a = of(a, number);
   }
   ```

Comment: Do you mean `Long.MIN_VALUE`?

Comment: I said 2 or more arguments. Your code allows the user to provide only 1 argument.

Comment: Linked to some SO question mentioning the problem. Yes, `Long.MIN_VALUE` is the one. Yes, my code does allow a single argument. But that simplifies the code, and where's the harm to that generalization?

Comment: What is the Greatest *Common* Divisor of 42?

Comment: Of 42 and nothing else? 42 naturally.

Comment: Please read the article carefully: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor

Comment: Yes? I'm not quite sure which part you want to lead me to.

Comment: The first line : *"In mathematics, the greatest common divisor of two or more integers"*

Comment: So? That doesn't mean the generalization isn't useful, or not valid.

Comment: How is it useful? It is *undefined* for less than two integers.

Comment: Well, it isn't undefined. If you receive 0 arguments, then yeah you have a problem, but the GCD of 42 is 42 and that's a valid answer after all!

Answer (score 4):

<strike>I think there's a bug in your method. If I call `GCD.of(0,0);` You'd return `b`, which equals `0`. But `0` isn't the GCD of `0`. Zero **can't ever** be a greatest common divisor. Because, you can't divide by zero. You should consider throwing a `DivideByZeroException`, because once you're there there's nothing else you can do!</strike> **Edit** : Thanks to @Deduplicator's comment which pointed at [a question on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495119/what-is-gcd0-0) You should return 0 if one of the parameter is 0!

To push on Deduplicator's idea, I think you should only receive **one** argument.

```
public static long of(long... numbers)
//See the rest of the review
```

- Now, what if the user passes **zero** arguments? Throw an exception, the user decided, by him(her)self, to pass zero arguments to a GCD function, it's dumb and the user will have to deal with the consequences of his(her) acts.
- What if the user passes only **one** argument. Well that's an easy job for you, you return the same number. The user **decided** to ask for the GCD of one number, give it to him.
- The user passes more than 1 `long`, good, now the real work begins!

```
public static long of(long... numbers) {
    if(numbers.length == 0) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Input is too small to compute GCD");
    }

    if(numbers.length == 1) {
        return numbers[0];
    }

    long gcd = numbers[0];
    //Note that the index starts at one because we use [0] for the first variable.
    for(int index = 1; index < numbers.length;index++){

        long number = numbers[index];
        if(number == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        gcd = of(gcd, number);
    }

    return gcd;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is only a mild improvement, and whether or not you call it an improvement is subjective.

Your second function:

```
public static long of(long a, long b, long... others) {
    long gcd = of(a, b);
    for (long number : others) {
        gcd = of(gcd, number);
    }
    return gcd;
}
```

Can be rewritten using Java 8's stream operators:

```
public static long of(long a, long... others) {
    return LongStream.concat(
               LongStream.of(a),
               LongStream.of(others)
           ).reduce(0, GCD::of);
}
```

And if you are fine with the user being able to call `GCD.of()`, you could do:

```
public static long of(long... values) {
    return LongStream.of(values)
                     .reduce(0, GCD::of);
}
```

This has the advantage of being easily parallelizable (which is actually only beneficial if you anticipate having a very large amount of values to find the gcd of):

```
public static long of(long... values) {
    return LongStream.of(values).parallel()
                     .reduce(0, GCD::of);
}
```

Comment: Ingenious! I *was* looking for a way to use Functional Programming.

Comment: Didn't know about  Java8 stream-operators yet. That makes the generalization look even better!